# Write Check Marks in RMarkdown?

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I try some examples from LaTeX, such as `\Checkedbox`, `\CrossedBox*`, `\HollowBox`, but unfortunately, they all do not work. I found `$\Box$`, `$\checkmark$`. Anyone know how to type checked box?

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own command which overlays `\checkmark` on top of `\Box`:

[image]

```
\newcommand{\boxedcheckmark}
  {{\ooalign{$\Box$\cr\hidewidth$\checkmark$\hidewidth}}}

I found $\Box$, $\checkmark$. Anyone know how to type checked box?
Check $\boxedcheckmark$ to see if it suits your needs.
```