# Check box in Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

Looking to make check boxes in Rmarkdown, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47112505/write-check-marks-in-rmarkdown) link, but trying to avoid latex. on the Rmarkdown cheatsheet there isn't a checkbox example. but the code below is markdown, but doesn't render.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Daniel"
date: "6/13/2020"
output: html_document
---
```{r}

```
- [ ] Venus
- [x] Mars
````

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to use raw HTML code to do that:

```
- <input type="checkbox" unchecked> Venus</input>
- <input type="checkbox" checked> Mars</input>
```

This will render to:

[image: Example]